# Generate short temporary link to a form

Tags: django

So, I have a form that logged in user can fill, and when that form is submitted, I'd like it to generate a temporary link to another form that non-logged in users could access and fill, that would last 24 hours. That form would then send data to the database. That link would be valid only several times. that number is determined in the first form, by the logged in user.

I would like that URL to be as short as possible and easy to write down manually on a browser, but I don't know the best way to do so, or even how to do so.

The first form is completed, and only logged in user can fill it, but I do not know how to generate that temporary link.

Please keep in mind that I am fairly new to Django.

Views.py

```
class GenFormPageView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
login_url = '/'

def get(selfself, request, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formation_form = genForm(data=request.POST)

        if formation_form.is_valid():
            cdata = formation_form.cleaned_data.get
        else:
            print('Invalid')
    else:
        formation_form = genForm()
        return render(request, 'genform.html', {'formation_form': formation_form})
```

Forms.py

```
class genForm(forms.ModelForm):
liste_formation = []
formations_info = {}
for formation in Formation.objects.all():
    if formation.libelle in formations_info:
        formations_info[formation.libelle].append(formation.formateur, formation.dateDebut, formation.dateFin,
                                                  formation.nbJours, formation.cours)
    else:
        info = {'formateur':formation.formateur.get_full_name(), 'dateDebut':formation.get_debut(), 'dateFin':formation.get_fin(), 'nbJours':formation.nbJours, 'cours':formation.cours.get_titre()}
        formations_info[formation.libelle] = info
    liste_formation.append(formations_info)

formations = [str(formation) for formation in Formation.objects.all()]

formation_select = forms.ChoiceField(label='Formation', choices=([(formation, formation) for formation in formations]), required = True)
formateur = forms.CharField(label='Formateur')
cours = forms.CharField(label='Cours')
nombre_eleves = forms.IntegerField(label='Nombre d\'élèves', min_value=1)

formations = json.dumps(formations_info)

class Meta:
    model = Formation
    fields = ('formation_select', 'formateur', 'dateDebut', 'dateFin', 'nbJours', 'cours', 'nombre_eleves')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^genform/$', views.GenFormPageView.as_view()),
```

Here is the field tht is going to determine the number of time the new form can be submitted

[image]

When I click the button 'Generer', it creates a link to a form. that form can only be submitted a fixed number of time, and the link can only lead to that form if clicked within 24 hours from the generated time.

What I am trying right now, is creating a field in my database containing the time when the form is generated, and then I will check if the time is valid, and display the form only if it is.

That my idea right now, but I still don't konw how to do it.

Comment: ok first add a decorator "@login_required" over your view/form validation and when you want some token look into this post https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html. You can generate a token which will be valid for 24 hours and is invalid once used

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear enough, I will edit my post to clarify, but the generated link must last 24 hours, but is valid not only once, but several times (the number of times is determined by the first form)

Comment: I think you can use django session. Can you explain more? About your views, urls and so on.

Comment: Ok just edited the post with a lot more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my question, I finally decided to use a field in my database containing the date of the creation of the form, then I would just check that today's date is within 24 hours from the date in my database.